# Как получить данные из запроса в переменную node.js https request

Tags: node.js

С node.js/JavaScript знаком только второй день. Мне необходимо создать два последовательных https запроса в node.js. Для этого использую библиотеку [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request). Результат первого запроса json, который я использую во втором запросе. Никак не могу передать значение из первого запроса в глобальную переменную для последующей передачи во второй запрос. 
Погуглив, понял что мне нужно двигаться в сторону callback или async/await, но что-то у меня в этом загвоздка. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

```js
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var requestHTTPS = require('request');
var querystring = require('querystring');

var filemakerToken = '';

function onRequest(request, response) {
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received. I will create record.");
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});

 if (pathname == "/createRecord") {
//   response.write("\n");
  response.write("i will create record");

  createRecordFilemaker();
  // authorisationFilemaker();

        // setTimeout(createRecordFilemaker, 1500);
  // createRecordFilemaker(filemakerToken);

        // console.log('must be new token: ', filemakerToken);

        // var lastToken = authorisationFilemaker();
        // console.log('last token from onReq: ', filemakerToken);

 }   else {
  response.write("i don't understand you request");
 }
//     response.write("Hello World");
    response.end();
}


function authorisationFilemaker(filemakerToken) {
    //Авторизация
    var postPrepare = { layout: "vibroTable", password: "admin", user: "admin"};
    var options = {
        "rejectUnauthorized": false,
        // strictSSL: false,
        url: 'https://10.0.1.10/fmi/rest/api/auth/workShopData',
        method: "POST",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify(postPrepare)
    };

    (async () => {

        await requestHTTPS(options, function (error, response, body) {
            console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
            console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
            console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
            var tokenJSON = JSON.parse(body);
            filemakerToken = tokenJSON.token;
            // filemakerToken = querystring.parse(requestResult);
            setResult(filemakerToken);
            // console.log('JSON:', tokenJSON);
            console.log('filemakerToken get from request:', filemakerToken);
        });

    })();
    // console.log('must be new token: ', filemakerToken);
}

function createRecordFilemaker(filemakerToken) {
    filemakerToken = authorisationFilemaker(filemakerToken);
    console.log('filemakerToken when create record:', filemakerToken);
    var postPrepare = {"data":{}};
    var options = {
        "rejectUnauthorized": false,
        // strictSSL: false,
        url: 'https://10.0.1.10/fmi/rest/api/record/workShopData/vibroTable',
        method: "POST",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'FM-Data-token': 'filemakerToken'
  },
        body: JSON.stringify(postPrepare)
    };

    requestHTTPS(options, function (error, response, body) {
        console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
        console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.

    });
}

function setResult(requestResult) {
    filemakerToken = requestResult;
    console.log('filemakerToken from func:', filemakerToken);
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8080);
console.log("Server has started.");
```

**UPD.** Пока нашёл промежуточное решение в виде задержки выполнения функций с заданным интервалом. Результат передал во внешнюю переменную с помощью дополнительной функции (хотя почему напрямую из запроса нельзя обновить глобальную переменную для меня загадка, возможно это связано с асинхроонностью js)

```js
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var requestHTTPS = require('request');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var filemakerToken = "empty";
var makeRequest;

function onRequest(request, response) {
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received. I will create record.");
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});

 if (pathname == "/createRecord") {
//   response.write("\n");
  response.write("i will create record");

        authorisationFilemaker();
  // createRecordFilemaker();
  // console.log('makeRequest: ', makeRequest);



        setTimeout(createRecordFilemaker, 100);
  // createRecordFilemaker(filemakerToken);

        // console.log('must be new token: ', filemakerToken);

        // var lastToken = authorisationFilemaker();
        // console.log('last token from onReq: ', filemakerToken);

 }   else {
  response.write("i don't understand you request");
 }
//     response.write("Hello World");
    response.end();
}


function authorisationFilemaker() {
    //Авторизация
    // var body;
    let postPrepare = { layout: "vibroTable", password: "admin", user: "admin"};
    var options = {
        "rejectUnauthorized": false,
        // strictSSL: false,
        url: 'https://10.0.1.10/fmi/rest/api/auth/workShopData',
        method: "POST",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify(postPrepare)
    };

    requestHTTPS(options, (error, response, body) => {
        console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
        console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
        var tokenJSON = JSON.parse(body);
        filemakerToken = tokenJSON.token;
        console.log('filemakerToken get from request:', filemakerToken);
        sayConsole(filemakerToken);
    });
}

function sayConsole (mess) {
    filemakerToken = mess;
    console.log("WWWW", filemakerToken);
}

function createRecordFilemaker() {

    // filemakerToken = authorisationFilemaker();
    var d = new Date(Date.now());
    var ddd = formatDate(d);
    var ttt = formatTime(d);
    console.log('DATE%%%', ddd);
    console.log('TIME%%%', ttt);

    console.log('filemakerToken when create record:', filemakerToken);
    var postPrepare = {"data":{creator: "node.js", date: ddd, time: ttt}};
    var options = {
        "rejectUnauthorized": false,
        // strictSSL: false,
        url: 'https://10.0.1.10/fmi/rest/api/record/workShopData/vibroTable',
        method: "POST",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'FM-Data-token': filemakerToken
  },
        body: JSON.stringify(postPrepare)
    };

    requestHTTPS(options, function (error, response, body) {
        console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
        console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
        console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.

    });
}

function formatDate(date) {

    var dd = date.getDate();
    if (dd < 10) dd = '0' + dd;

    var mm = date.getMonth() + 1;
    if (mm < 10) mm = '0' + mm;

    var yy = date.getFullYear();
    if (yy < 10) yy = '0' + yy;

    return mm + '.' + dd + '.' + yy;
}

function formatTime(time) {
    var hh = time.getHours();
    var mm = time.getMinutes();
    var ss = time.getSeconds();

    return hh + ':' + mm + ':' + ss;
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8080);
// https.createServer(onRequest).listen(443);
console.log("Server has started.");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function authorisationFilemaker(filemakerToken) {
    //Авторизация
    var postPrepare = { layout: "vibroTable", password: "admin", user: "admin"};
    var options = {
        "rejectUnauthorized": false,
        // strictSSL: false,
        url: 'https://10.0.1.10/fmi/rest/api/auth/workShopData',
        method: "POST",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify(postPrepare)
    };


    requestHTTPS(options, (error, response, body) => {
            console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
            console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
            console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
            var tokenJSON = JSON.parse(body);
            filemakerToken = tokenJSON.token;
            // filemakerToken = querystring.parse(requestResult);
            setResult(filemakerToken);
            // console.log('JSON:', tokenJSON);
            console.log('filemakerToken get from request:', filemakerToken);
    });
    // console.log('must be new token: ', filemakerToken);
}
```

Как вы видите я изменил функцию где идет присвоение переменной, такой вариант должен работать.

Comment: К сожалению данный вариант не работает. Вот часть консоли: "must be new token:  undefined
filemakerToken when create record: undefined" Переменная видна только в requestHTTPS и в function setResult

Comment: Это происходит потому что вам нужно сделать переменную глобальной, объявите ее в самом начале кода, до функции, и присвойте ей `null`.

Comment: Давно сделал, шестая строка в коде. Только что попробовал присвоить ей null - без результата, за пределами функции переменная - undefined.

Comment: Попробуйте переменной внутри функции задать какое-то статическое значение.

Comment: Добавил такой код:        `console.log('filemakerToken get from request:', filemakerToken);
    });
    filemakerToken = "manualyValue";
    console.log('must be new token: ', filemakerToken);
}` Сообщение в консоли не радует: `must be new token:  manualyValue
filemakerToken when create record: undefined`. Я так понимаю всё дело в асинхронности выполнения кода.

Comment: Не могу понять почему не работают callback и async/await, они бы решили мою проблему :(

Answer (score 0):

Используйте промисы.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');


Promise.resolve(/*Здесь передаете параметры*/)
  .then(onRequest(/*Так же и здесь передаете параметры*/)) // P.S. Делайте функции верно, каждая функция должна что-то возвращать. **return smthng;**
  .catch(err => {if (err) throw new Error(err)})
  .then(value => {authorisationFilemaker(/*Здесь можно использовать значение, которое возвращает Ваша функция onRequest*/)})
  .catch(err => {if (err) trow new Error(err)})
  .then(value => {console.log(value)});
```

Сама либа: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Уже два дня пытаюсь понять как мне прикрутить этот код в мой - безрезультатно. Async/await вроде проще и из коробки, но тоже почему-то не работает...

Comment: Что именно не получается? Ошибки? или работает без ошибок, но не так, как ожидалось? Больше информации, пожалуйста

Comment: Как я писал в начале, я всего несколько дней как начал пользоваться node.js/JS. Для меня к сожалению пока не понятна конструкция предложенного Вами промиса. Надо будет ещё посмотреть примеры по проще. Свою задачу я решил, хотя и через костыли (решение в первом посте).